# AVAudioPlayer direct to speaker / headphones instead of earpiece iOS 7

Tags: ios6, ios7, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am using the following code to play a recording.  In iOS 6 the output is automatically directed to the speaker / headphones.  However in iOS 7 the audio is directed to the earpiece.  Has AVAudioPlayer behaviour changed in iOS 7?

```
    if (!recorder.recording){
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
    [player setDelegate:(id)self];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
}
```

Comment: I am having this exact same problem.  I fixed it by overriding the audio output to force it to the speakers, but now if someone attaches external speakers or a headset, the audio will not route appropriately.  Have you made any more headway here?

Comment: I managed to fix it by specifying the audio session as play only, rather than record and play.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 just changes defaults and now audio is routed to headphones by default. To change defaults insert this snippet anywhere in your code, doesn't matter before you instantiate AVAudioPlayer or after.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);
```